# Security screening location Sydney TWOV

Tags: sydney, twov

I know I don't need a visa when transiting Sydney Airport from one international to another international airport; however, I am aware I have to clear security and not customs.  I have found no maps showing this area; they all show clearing customs.  Anyone know where such a map exists?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any maps showing what you're looking for, but from experience I can show you where the transfer locations are...

The maps that do exist for Sydney Airport are on [this page on their website](https://www.sydneyairport.com.au/info-sheet/maps).

For the International Terminal there are 2 maps that are relevant - one showing the arrivals level, and the other showing departures.  Unfortunately the Arrivals map doesn't include the area of the terminal that you're interested in - however the two levels are simply 2 levels of the same building - with the departures area being above the arrivals level.

If you look at the Departures map, there are two escalators/elevators shown in what is roughly the central area of each of the wings of the terminal - one shown near gate 58, and the other near gate 30.

The escalators in these locations on the map likely actually refer to the escalators to go from the Departures floor to the floor above (where some of the airport lounges are located), however at the same location is a separate escalator which comes from the arrivals level up to the departures level, and it is this escalator that is used when doing an airside transit.

Obviously the arrivals level has the same layout in terms of gate positions and escalator locations as the departures map shows, so this will give you a fair idea of how to get from any specific gate to the nearest of the two transfer areas.

Of course, the simple answer is to simply follow the signs to the transfer area - the area is well signposted and will lead you directly to where you need to go.

Once you arrive in the transfer area you can visit the transfer desk if needed (eg, to get a new boarding pass), then pass through security, go up the escalator, and you will be in the departure area, from where you can proceed to your gate (which may be in the other wing of the terminal!)

Comment: When in doubt, ask somebody in the terminal wearing a uniform. They're used to answering questions from lost tourists...